# date_trunch week without timestamp value

Tags: sql

I want to extract the week in a group by as below

```
select date_trunc('week', date_created) as wk, count(transaction_id)
from table 
group by 1
```

but I want my output to just have the week and not a timestamp of 0:00:00 with the week

how can I alter code to have that output? Thanks

```
current output
12-05-20 0:00:00

desired output
12-05-20
```

Answer (score 1):

in postgres you can cast output to date

```
select '12-05-20 0:00:00'::date ;

->2020-05-12
```

in your case

```
select date_trunc('week', date_created)::date as wk, count(transaction_id)
from table 
group by 1
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do this using cast as well?